# P=NP: What are the most promising methods?

Tags: computer-science, theory, np, p-np

I know that P=NP has not been solved up to now, but can anybody tell me something about the following: What are currently the most promising mathematical / computer scientific methods that *could* be helpful to tackle this problem? Or are there even none such methods known to be potentially helpful up to now? Is there any (free) compendium on this topic where I can find all / most of the research done in this area?

Comment: Nitpic: you wrote P minus NP.  The great question is whether P=NP (P equals NP).  Often written as P=NP?   The first promising subset is to consider only NP-complete problems, not all NP problems.  I suggest re-phrasing the question to deal only with NP-complete problems.

Comment: Subjective and off topic, I'm sorry. I won't insult you with the obvious suggestions about where to look instead of here.

Comment: @bmargulies: How is this off topic?

Comment: @sepp2k way off in theoretical computer science, which is not programming. However, I see that my close vote is entirely lonely, so I guess I'm wrong this time.

Comment: I think we won't know which method of proof is most promising until a proof is actually found (either way).  If you want to know which methods of approximating an NP-complete problem are currently the most promising approximations, that's a completely different question which does have answers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theoretical computer science, which is more appropriate at cs.stackexchange.com or cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An excellent overview appeared last year in Communications of the ACM. I think it became the most downloaded article of CACM ever, so your question may be relevant after all :-)

[The Status of the P=NP Problem](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2009/9/38904-the-status-of-the-p-versus-np-problem/fulltext), Lance Fortnow, Communications of the ACM, Vol. 52 No. 9, 2009